# Making a C program smaller

Tags: c

I have a very small C program which reverses a file. It compiles on windows to an `exe` file of size 28,672 bytes.

- What is the best approach for reducing the file size?
- Are there any tools that can tell me what takes the most space? (included libraries)
- Is this size normal for such a simple program?
- What compiler flags should I use to reduce file size (`/O1` and `/Os` doesn't seem to make any effect)?

BTW - when compiled with `gcc` I get around 50Kb file and when compiled with `cl` I get 28Kb.

*EDIT: Here is the code*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   FILE *fi, *fo;

   char *file1, file2[1024];
   long i, length;
   int ch;

   file1 = argv[1];

   file2[0] = 0;
   strcat(file2, file1);
   strcat(file2, ".out");

   fo = fopen(file2,"wb");
   if( fo == NULL )
   {
      perror(file2);
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   fi = fopen(file1,"rb");
   if( fi == NULL )
   {
      fclose(fo);
      return 0;
   }

   fseek(fi, 0L, SEEK_END);
   length = ftell(fi);
   fseek(fi, 0L, SEEK_SET);

   i = 0;
   while( ( ch = fgetc(fi) ) != EOF ) {
      fseek(fo, length - (++i), SEEK_SET);
      fputc(ch,fo);
   }

   fclose(fi);
   fclose(fo);
   return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

- Compiling with `/MD` produced a 16Kb file.
- Compiling with `tcc` (Tiny C Compiler) produced a 2Kb file.
- Compiling with `gcc -s -O2` produced a 8Kb file.

Comment: You realize it's hard to answer in detail when we can't see your code, right? Just you saying it's "very small" doesn't give a lot to go on.

Comment: Are you using dynamic linking for libc?

Comment: `perror( file2 )` produces an error message that is useful.  `perror( "ERROR" )` produces an error message that is incredibly annoying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to compile it using tcc: http://bellard.org/tcc/ .

Comment: This is awesome! It compiled to a 2Kb exe (14 times smaller!)

Comment: hmm.. `-s -O2` are very gcc useful flags.

Comment: @zenpoy: Don't get too excited about this result. Different compilers / libraries make that much of a difference because your application only actually *uses* a very small part of the library. A larger application (which uses more of the standard functions) won't turn out to be 14 times smaller just because you compile it with TCC, or a different lib.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Let it be said by someone who implemented his own version of the stdio functions: They are quite big, and somewhat interdependent. Linking one of them links in several others automatically.

Since this is a one-time cost, and doesn't matter in the scope of big applications, most libraries don't bother much with optimizing this away.

That being said, compiling into a *dynamically* linking executable instead of a static one is usually the way to go. If you *have* to have a statically linked executable, you might want to look at one of the libraries optimized for embedded environments, as they are more focussed on small-size optimizations like this.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [`-s`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options) gcc flag:

> -s
>       Remove all symbol table and relocation information from the executable.

A test with small C program that I'm developing:

Without `-s`: **120,2 Kib**

With    `-s`: **58,3  Kib**

By removing dead code from your executable:

By using `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections` the compiler will put the unused function into separed section that by using `-Wl,--gc-sections` will be removed by the `link.

The file size now is: **50,2 Kib**

By `-O2`

do a lot of optimizations, but without increase file size, usually, unlike.

The file size now is: **42,1 KiB**

gcc there is too some `-O*` to optimization in favor to file size.

Answer (score 1):

Which libraries do you use?
You don't need any libraries for reversing a file in C except the standard lib. Then your executable should be no larger than 2kb.

However if I compile:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

with MinGW, the size of the executable is equal to 48kb. But I haven't used any optimalization flags.

Edit: With the -s flag, it reduces to 7,5 kb.